# Atraso de minutos ao salvar registro PHP

Tags: php

Tenho um formulário de inscrição e **nos testes**, ao finalizar o cadastro, ele armazena a hora correta, porém quando disponibilizo ao usuário final, os registros são armazenados com atraso de aproximadamente 7 minutos.

Ou seja, disponibilizo às 19:00 e quando vejo na base de dados existem cadastros de 18:53 pra cima, e a hora do servidor está correta(19:00).

**Windows Server 2008 R2**
**Xampp com Apache 2.0 e PHP 5.4**

No **php.ini** a date.timezone = America/Recife

Código da aplicação:

```
   private function dataAtual(){
      return date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
   }
```

Insert

```
   $query = "INSERT INTO boletos (linguaID,candidatoID, concursoID, nDocumento, dataVenc, 
        dataDocumento, dataProcessamento, aceite, especie, valUnitario, quantidade, especieDoc, contaCedente,ccDigito,agencia) 
        values (".$bolet->getLinguaID().",".$_SESSION['candidatoID'].",".$_SESSION['concursoID'].",'".$bolet->getNDocumento()."'
        ,'".$bolet->getDataVenc()."','".$bolet->dataAtual()."','".$bolet->dataAtual()."',
        '".$bolet->getAceite()."','".$bolet->getEspecie()."',".$bolet->getValUnitario().",".$bolet->getQuantidade().",
        '".$bolet->getEspecieDoc()."','".$empresa->getContaCedente()."','".$empresa->getCCDigito()."','".$empresa->getAgencia()."')";
```

A data em questão é a **"dataDocumento"**.

Não consegui encontrar nada relacionado na web.

Comment: Oi, Daniel.
Inseri na pergunta o trecho mais relevante, e segue o resultado da query que você passou:

NOW() => 2016-10-20 10:49:07
CURDATE() => 2016-10-20
CURTIME() => 10:49:07

Comment: Oi amigo, o problema é que todos esses testes funcionam feitos da minha máquina, ou de qualquer outra da empresa, fiz até de casa modificando a hora do meu PC, mas em todos os testes obtive sucesso, ele sempre pega a hora correta(do servidor). Só não entendo porque não funciona quando em produção, sempre tem algum cadastro que fica alguns minutos abaixo da hora de liberação das inscrições.  Loucura, né!?

Comment: Desculpa, quando falei em produção, quis dizer quando liberado o link para as inscrições, mas o ambiente que fiz os testes foi no de produção, ou seja, o mesmo.